# Powerline installed without vim bindings

Tags: vim, powerline-plugin

Using Ubuntu 16.04, I installed powerline (`sudo apt install powerline`); I enabled it for bash successfully, but when I tried to enable it in my `.vimrc` file, using the following lines:

```
" Powerline
set rtp+=/usr/share/powerline/bindings/vim/
set laststatus=2
set t_Co=256
```

it didn't work. I did some troubleshooting, and discovered that `/usr/share/powerline/bindings/vim/` doesn't exist, although there are folders for a number of other bindings (e.g., bsh, awesome, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

For those here from Google, add the following to `~/.vimrc` if you have installed powerline from your distribution (sudo apt-get install powerline).

```
set rtp+=/usr/share/vim/addons/
set laststatus=2
set t_Co=256
```

Comment: Perfect! I had almost exhaused trying everything else! :)

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
sudo cp -r /home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/powerline/bindings/vim /usr/share/powerline/bindings
```

fixed for me, on Ubuntu 16.04. Please replace `$USER` accordingly. You may also need to replace `python3.5` folder in that path with the correct python version for which powerline has been installed.

I don't know why binding for vim is not available system-wide by default, i.e. placed under `/usr/share/powerline/bindings/`, though.